# Geofence Transition Error: invalid transition type -1

Tags: java, android

Geofence transition error:

> invalid transition type -1

`geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition()` returns `-1` instead of `1`

```
int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();
```

`geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition()` must return enter and exit values that is `1` and `2` respectively.

Comment: What error code do you get when you run `getErrorCode()`? Also, the `-1` applies when `if the intent specified in fromIntent(Intent) is not generated for a transition alert then the value is -1; else, it will returns the GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ flags value defined in Geofence`.

Answer (score 0):

In google documentation, I found this sentence about a [getGeofenceTransition()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingEvent#public-int-getgeofencetransition-) method: "returns -1 if the intent specified in fromIntent(Intent) is not generated for a transition alert; Otherwise returns the GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ flags value defined in Geofence."

That means the intent you received in onReceive() or onHandleWork() method **is not generated for transition alert** (exit, enter or dwell).

For example, that intent can be the *intent generated to restore a geofence after the device is rebooted.* ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED").

In the case of receiving a BOOT_COMPLETED intent in your onReceive() method, it will pass the geofencingEvent.hasError() method with no error at all but that type of geofence transitions with code -1 doesn't match to any of [transition alerts](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingRequest.html#constants_1) (exit, enter or dwell).

In such a case you need to handle separately like in this example:

```
public class GeofenceTransitionsCatcher extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


   GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);

   if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
   String errorMessage=GeofenceStatusCodes.getStatusCodeString(geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
        Log.i("TRANSITION", errorMessage);

    }

   int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

   if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER) {

        Log.i("TRANSITION", "ENTER - geofenceTransition code = 1");

    } else if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {
         Log.i("TRANSITION", "EXIT - geofenceTransition code = 2");


    } else if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL) {

        Log.i("TRANSITION", "DWELL - geofenceTransition code = 4");


    } else {

        Log.i("TRANSITION", "NOT GEOFENCE TRANSITION - geofenceTransition code = -1");
       //HERE IS GEOFENCE TRANSITION CODE -1

    }
    }
```